# telnet disabled, server 2012r2 still listening on port 23

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, telnet

How else can I disable telnet to comply with a security audit? The Telnet services roles are not enabled on this server. But it is LISTENING at 0.0.0.0:23. Also there is no local windows firewall to utilize.

Comment: _"Also there is no local windows firewall to utilize."_ ಠ_ಠ

Comment: this is an enterprise org. the windows firewall is disabled on all servers in favor of a variety of other solutions like layer 2/3 firewalls, file execution inspection, AV, agent-based security, etc. is that strange or something?

Comment: @Benjy: it's a bad "something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
netstat -a -b -n -o
```

Find the process listening on port 23. From there, find the service or application that launches that process and stop it.